# javaFX text fields and listeners

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I am facing a situation where there are two text fields with 2 seperate listeners for each of them.

TextField customerId and TextField customerName.

> 1000    mohan
>
> 1002    mithun

I am trying to automatically update other text field when one text field  is filled eg if customerId 1000 is filled then corresponding customer name mohan get updated to text field customerName ,and if mohan is filled then his customer id 1000 will get filled in customerId text field.I am using maps,The problem is when one text field filled its listener is called which call backs the same text field listener and this causes cycles finally ending up with lot off errors.What should i do to solve this ?

Minimal example

```
    Map<String, String> treeMapCustomerName,treeMapCustomerId;

     treeMapCustomerName=new TreeMap<String,String>();
     treeMapCustomerId=new TreeMap<String,String>();
String customerName="mohan";
String customerId="1000";

treeMapCustomerId.put("1000","Mohan");
treeMapCustomerId.put("1002","Mithun");

treeMapCustomerName.put("Mohan","1000");
treeMapCustomerName.put("Mithun","1002");




        customerName.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        customerId.setText(treeMapCustomerName.get(customerName));//immediately customerId textfield listener is triggered which will trigger this listener causing cycles  

        });

        customerId.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        customerName.setText(treeMapCustomerId.get(customerId));

        });
```

Comment: Surely the only errors you can get here are null pointer exceptions, because the calls you have to `treeMapCustomerName.get(...)` and `treeMapCustomerId.get(...)` must return `null` (you are passing text fields to the `get` method, and you never - indeed cannot - associate any values in the map with text fields, so the `get()` calls return `null`).

Comment: Yeah you are right,now it been fixed

Comment: and how can i remove redundant code

Comment: @James_D   am I wrong about this "immediately customerId textfield listener is triggered which will trigger this listener causing cycles". I am fairly new to javafx ,I know i need to understand lots of concepts.

Comment: It doesn't cause cycles, it should stop after a couple of iterations (at most). (Just think: you type in the name field, that will cause `customerId.setText(null)`, which triggers the listener on `customerId`: that in turn causes either a null pointer exception or `customerName.setText(null)`. If the last one doesn't cause a null pointer exception, it causes `customerId.setText(null);` which does nothing as the value is already null.) Doesn't much matter, I think in retrospect you probably need to check the value exists in the map (or at least check the new value is not null or empty).

Comment: yes you are right. I will do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't taking advantage of your new values, instead you are accessing the map with the control, which will throw errors at run time

You could check if the map contains your key and only update the other text field if it is present, something like the below:

```
            customerName.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if(treeMapCustomerName.containsKey(newValue)){
                    customerId.setText(treeMapCustomerName.get(newValue));
                }
            });

            customerId.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if(treeMapCustomerId.containsKey(newValue)){
                    customerName.setText(treeMapCustomerId.get(newValue));
                }
            });
```

This will avoid issues with checking the map before a complete id / username has been entered, however this won't account for issues where a value being entered is a sub string of another.

E.g. If the map contained id's 100, 1000, 10000 and you don't want each of these to display as the user types 10000, you may need an additional control such as a button instead of using the property